# ImageButton becomes non-clickable on setting background in XML file

Tags: java, android, xml, imagebutton

So I am trying to create an audio player app and in it, the play button works fine without setting any background but as soon as I set a background in XML file , that ImageButton becomes non-clickable . So can someone help me with that ? Thanks

**XML File :**

```
 <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:weightSum="1"
            android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright">


                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/btnPrevious"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_weight="2.40"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/btn_previous" />

                <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btnPlay1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:background="@drawable/btn_play" />



                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/btnNext"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:paddingLeft="230dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/btn_next" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
```

**btn_play.xml :**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/download4"
        android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/az"/>
</selector>
```

**PlayListActivity.java :**

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_play_list);

        mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        ListView mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        mMusicList = getAudioList();

   ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mMusicList);
        mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int arg2,
                                    long arg3) {

                try {
                    playSong(mAudioPath[arg2]);
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
    }

    private String[] getAudioList() {
        final Cursor mCursor = getContentResolver().query(
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                new String[]{MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA}, null, null,
                "LOWER(" + MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE + ") ASC");

        int count = mCursor.getCount();

        String[] songs = new String[count];
        mAudioPath = new String[count];
        int i = 0;
        if (mCursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                songs[i] = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME));
                mAudioPath[i] = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA));
                i++;
            } while (mCursor.moveToNext());
        }

        mCursor.close();

        return songs;
    }


    private void playSong(String path) throws IllegalArgumentException,
            IllegalStateException, IOException {

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_android_building_music_player);
        Log.d("ringtone", "playSong :: " + path);

        mMediaPlayer.reset();
        mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(path);
//mMediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
        mMediaPlayer.prepare();
        mMediaPlayer.start();
        acv(path);
        abc();
    }

    public void acv(String path) {
        getInit();

        metaRetriver = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
        metaRetriver.setDataSource(path);
        try {
            art = metaRetriver.getEmbeddedPicture();
            Bitmap songImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(art, 0, art.length);
            album_art.setImageBitmap(songImage);
            album.setText(metaRetriver
                    .extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM));
            artist.setText(metaRetriver
                    .extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            album_art.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
            album.setText("Unknown Album");
            artist.setText("Unknown Artist");
        }

    }

    public void getInit() {
        album_art = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.coverart1);
        album = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Album);
        artist = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.artist_name);
    }


    public  void abc(){
        ImageButton btnPlay1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnPlay1);
        btnPlay1.setOnClickListener(
                new ImageButton.OnClickListener(){
                    public void onClick(View v){
                        if (mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                            mMediaPlayer.pause();
                        } else {
                            mMediaPlayer.start();
                        }

                    }
                });
    }
```

Comment: What makes you think the button is not clickable? When I create a tiny app that just has your row of image buttons with assigned `View.OnClickListener`s, I see the click events firing.

Comment: well then maybe there's something wrong with rest of the Java code or with btn_play.xml because in my app , song playing is not paused even on clicking the button a number of times

Comment: and it happens only after setting the background, click events fire when there is no background set in XML file

Answer (score 0):

Change btn_play.xml with this

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/download4"
    android:state_pressed="false" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/az"
    android:state_pressed="true" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/az"
    android:state_selected="true" />
</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/download4"
        android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/az"
        android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/az" />
```

and remove this :

```
android:background="@null"
android:clickable="true"
```

change this :

```
android:background="@drawable/btn_play"
```

Modify RelativeLayout as below :

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">


            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btnPrevious"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:background="@drawable/btn_play" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btnPlay1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:background="@drawable/btn_play" />


            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btnNext"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:background="@drawable/btn_play" />
        </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: add this line in parent LinearLayout : android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"

Comment: I did, it changes nothing .

Comment: still no change :/

Comment: okay....then create proper adapter class for listview and write click event in adapter class....and then try..

Comment: An easier solution I tried was to set the Background using Java code but I still don't understand why I can't set it using XML

Answer (score 0):

Set this `android:clickable="true"` property in you button. Try this

```
<ImageButton
     android:id="@+id/btnPlay1"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_centerInParent="true"
     android:clickable="true"
     android:background="@drawable/btn_play" />
```

For create `<selector>`  to `<ImageButton>` Please [Check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12476898/how-to-use-a-selector-to-change-an-imagebutton-image) this.